# Should using be preferred over define for name aliasing in C++

Tags: c++, macros, using

Some cases we want name aliasing, and can decide `using` or `define` to be used, for example:

```
using ComponentRef = std::shared_ptr<Component>;

#define ComponentRef std::shared_ptr<Component>
```

Is there some reason for which one is preferred over another?

Comment: `#define` < `typdef` < `using`.

Answer (score 4):

You should prefer `using` simply because `#define` is a straight text substitution with no "smarts" behind it at all. `#define` also persists outside the scope where you declare it and may have strange unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer to use *anything* before a macro. Macros can mess up your code in unexpected ways, when a macro substitution happens where you didn't expect it.

Answer (score -1):

"Using" is better. If #define seems necessary, consider whether a "typedef" would serve instead:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Component> ComponentRef;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. I'm guessing they downvoted because using is generally better than typedef these days. Doesn't seem like that was your point here though.

Comment: I will get over it.